# Доступ к объекту класса из вложенного класса

Tags: java

```
public class MainMenuScreen extends GameScreen {
...
    btn.setClickListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void click(Button btn) {
            game.removeScreen(/*Вот здесь нужно получить доступ к объекту класса MainMenuScreen*/);
        }
    });
...
}
```

Выше в комментарии написано что мне нужно. Есть ли такая возможность?

Пока что вынес работу в отдельный метод

```
public class MainMenuScreen extends GameScreen {
...
    btn.setClickListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void click(Button btn) {
            startGameLoop();
        }
    });
...
    private void startGameLoop(){
             // нужная работа с обращением к this
    }
}
```

но интересует возможность прямого доступа именно в первом варианте.

Надеюсь доступно объяснил :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MainMenuScreen.this. - вот так.

Comment: Да, так даже разумнее.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно.

Answer (score 2):

в MainMenuScreen добавьте метод

```
private MainMenuScreen getInstance() {
  return this;
}
```

и дергайте на здоровье во внутренних классах.

Comment: Подобные решения (как и свое) я причислил к костылям :)

Я искал как раз решение предложенное kENNAAAAA

Comment: Не спорю. Просто последние несколько суток приходится пробрасывать экземпляры между разными уровнями разных иерархий, уже ум за разум заходит.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, что иметь доступ к полю из анонимного внутреннего класса, нужно пометить его как **final**.

Comment: тут речь не поле обрамляющего класса, а о самом экземпляре.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Неправильно вопрос понял.